# Add breakpoints on a single page with Elementor

Tags: css, wordpress, breakpoints, elementor

I used wordpress with elementor pro to create a website.
Having worked on a "normal" size PC, I didn't realize that there was a problem with responsiveness on a large screen (1920x1080px). This responsive problem, I only find it on my homepage. The breakpoints of my site are set by default (mobile, tablet, desktop). If I add breakpoints for larger screens, it messes up the responsiveness of my other pages. So I would like to add a breakpoint only on my home page, is this possible?

I tried to solve the problem by putting custom CSS like this :

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1920px) {
  selector{
  margin-bottom:100px;
  }
}
```

But it does not change anything...